# how to process multiple formats of data into hive

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive

this is my hdfs file .my file  contains 5 columns,like id,fname,lname,interest,address.how to store this data from hdfs to  hive.

```
 id         fname   lname              interest

654321.0    John      Doe        [ "electronics" , "sports" , "music"]  

                     address

{ "name" : "John Doe" , "company" : "Resultri" , "street" : "1015 Mapple   
Street" ,"city" : "San Francisco" , "state" : "CA" , "zip_code" : 94105.0}
```

any idea to process this?pelse shre hive query to process this

Answer (score 0):

http://rishavrohitblog.blogspot.in/2013/10/connecting-hive-to-mongodb-using.html

Can try using above Post.

Regards,
Chennakrishna